# How to escape /None in \foreach iterator?

Tags: pgffor

The last compiler to invoke is

```
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None frames.ps
```

for Windows or

```
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None frames.ps
```

for non-Windows.

The code snippet I want to invoke is as follows.

```
\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None/ps}
    {\immediate\write18{\compiler\space frames.\ext}}
```

But if you need the complete code, see my last answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141534/19356).

Probably the iterator gets confused with `/None` because `/` is used for the delimiter. How to escape `/None`?

Comment: What about `\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\string#/None}/ps}`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I tried it, but it doesn't work, because the braces aren't stripped off; `\@firstofone{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages/string#/None}/ps` works, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to only escape `/None`, but also `#` that's illegal in that context:

```
\edef\hms{\string#/}% Hash Mark Slash
\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\hms None/ps}
    {\immediate\write18{\compiler\space frames.\ext}}
```

The variant you mentioned in chat is even better:

```
\edef\AutoRotateOff{-dAutoRotatePages\string#/None}
\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,ps2pdf \AutoRotateOff/ps}
    {\immediate\write18{\compiler\space frames.\ext}}
```

Both exploit the fact that `\write` fully expands its argument.

Another variant:

```
\makeatletter
\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,%
  \@firstofone{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\string#/None}/ps}
    {\immediate\write18{\compiler\space frames.\ext}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @egreg's answer, the `/` can be removed from `\hms` but we need `{...}` for `ps2pdf` item as follows.

```
\edef\hms{\string#}

\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\hms/None}/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space temporary.\ext}}
```

### MWE

```
% this input file name is filename.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{temporary.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,2)
    \rput{90}(2,1){Marienplatz}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{graphicx,pgffor}
\edef\hms{\string#}

\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\hms/None}/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space temporary.\ext}}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{temporary}
\end{document}
```

### More about Windows

In my experience with Windows 7, both `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` and `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` work on Windows. Therefore, the simplest solution just needs `{...}` as follows.

```
% this input file name is filename.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{temporary.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,2)
    \rput{90}(2,1){Marienplatz}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{graphicx,pgffor}

\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None}/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space temporary.\ext}}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{temporary}
\end{document}
```

### Warning

Don't replace `\string#` with `\#` as `\#` will not work (I just tried it).

Comment: My experience with Windows is void. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

*edit (2017): since `xint 1.1 (2014/10/28)` one needed here `\usepackage{xinttools}`, not `\usepackage{xint}`.*

As  `\xintForpair` does not use `/` it is possible to have a simpler syntax:

```
% this input file name is filename.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{temporary.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,2)
    \rput{90}(2,1){Marienplatz}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\xintForpair #1#2 in 
   {(latex,tex),(dvips,dvi),(ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages\string#/None,ps)}
\do {\immediate\write18{#1 temporary.#2}}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{temporary}
\end{document}
```

Latest version of [xint](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) transparently removes spaces in comma separated lists, so the above may have all the additional spaces you desire around commas and parentheses.

Comment: It seems to me it will save more keystrokes.

Comment: @Marienplatz I am wondering why don't you use a single `\immediate\write18` with `&&`: `latex temporary.tex && dvips temporary.dvi && ps2pdf etc...`, is it something one can not do on windows? (assuming you are on windows).